# Как округлять абсолютное любое число, чтобы остаток был 0,5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например:

```
6.78 > 6.5
1.2 > 1.5
3 > 3.5
```

Через эту функцию не получается.

```
round()
```

Answer (score 7):

Отбросить дробную часть и прибавить `0.5`:

```
import math
x = math.trunc(x)+0.5
```

Answer (score 7):

Привести к целому и прибавить 0.5

```
x = int(x) + 0.5
```

Comment: чет я с просоня не догадался

Answer (score 2):

Через встроенный `round()`

```
x = round(x) - 0.5 if round(x) > x else round(x) + 0.5
```